# cabal fails to build simple project

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a simple existing Haskell project that *compiles fine* with ghc:

```
$ ghc src/*.hs
[1 of 3] Compiling Address          ( src/Address.hs, src/Address.o )
[2 of 3] Compiling Person           ( src/Person.hs, src/Person.o )
[3 of 3] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, src/Main.o )
Linking src/Main ...
```

I try to set up a cabal build but can't seem to succeed

```
$ cabal init --source-dir=src --main-is=src/Main.hs
$ cabal build
Resolving dependencies...
...<omitted for brevity>...
src/Main.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Person’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Person
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src/Main.hs:2:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Address’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
2 | import Address
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your cabal file is the problem. From your description it sounds like you have a file with the lines:

```
    main-is:          src/Main.hs
    hs-source-dirs:   .
```

I don't know how this manifests into the issue you post (and I have reproduced) but the normal form is to use the directory field to list the directory and the `main-is` field for just the file name:

```
    main-is:          Main.hs
    hs-source-dirs:   src
```

This works.  Also, both these are not conforming to cabal norms. Consider placing the modules under `src` and the executable Main under a directory named `app` or `my-projects-binary-name` if you want to look a little more like a directory structure that many devs have in mind.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly, I should manually edit the cabal file after executing `cabal init --source-dir=src --main-is=src/Main.hs` and change `hs-source-dirs: src` (indeed, it was created commented out ! weird !) and change `main-is: Main.hs`. What you suggest works for me - but isn't there anything simpler ??

Comment: Simpler than editing a file? I can't imagine much simpler. From the command line not using `src/Main.hs`, wish caused the original problem, would be simpler though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that using `--application-dir=src` instead of `--source-dir=src` works:

```
$ cabal init --main-is=Main.hs --application-dir=src
```

- Not sure if this is a bug or just confusing flag names (?)
- Anyway, it looks like *no manual editing* of the auto-generated cabal file is needed.